# Number of sequences which follow a given pattern

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

How to find the number of sequences of length K with elements from {0, 1,2 ... N} which follow a particular pattern?

If the pattern is strictly increasing or decreasing then its N choose K. What if the pattern is mixed?

Comment: what kind of pattern?

Comment: Say a pattern like -IIDDI, Where in positions 2,3,6 the number increases, and in positions 4,5 they decrease

Answer (score 1):

Any pattern:
$$_NP_K$$
Only decreasing:
$$_NC_K$$
Only increasing:
$$_NC_K$$
Mixed pattern:
$$_NP_K-2\cdot _NC_K=(K!-2)\cdot _NC_K$$

Comment: Not sure. In {0,1,2} if the required pattern is -DI, where D is decreasing and I is increasing. Then the following are the valid permutations: {1,0,2}, {2,0,1}. The above formula doesn't fit in?!?

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand what you meant by "mixed pattern". Did you mean DI and ID ?

Comment: By mixed pattern I meant both increasing and decreasing in a given pattern.

Comment: Okay, I modified my answer.

Comment: Can you explain what kind of mixed pattern is this expression for??

Comment: The only cases that are not mixed are only decreasing and only increasing.

Comment: Well, my interpretation was: DIDIDIDI is also a mixed pattern.

Comment: Can you please justify your reasoning(especially for the mixed pattern)

Comment: Mixed = mix of D and I (e.g., DI, ID, DID, IDI, DIDI, IDID, DIDID, DIDIDIDIDID...), Not-mixed = D, I (only 2 cases). Do I need to justify more??

Comment: Ok so this formula is for all mixed patterns. This doesn't give the number of sequences for a given pattern like IDIIID.

Comment: There is nothing like IDIIID. It's just IDID

Comment: Well it's a matter of different way of expression. In your expression, I included everything - IIIIIIID, IIIIDID, DDIDDIID, ..., except only two - IIIIIIII, DDDDDDDD